# Python - module has no attribute

Tags: python, module

I have downloaded and installed the `python` module `billboard.py` from `github` using `python setup.py install`, at `~/Downloads/`.

at first it was working, but after I changed directories where my script which imported the module was, it broke.

I have tried checking whether it is being imported, with:

```
import billboard
import sys

modulename = 'billboard'
if modulename not in sys.modules:
    print 'You have not imported the {} module'.format(modulename)
```

and *it is* indeed importing the module. but still, if I:

```
chart = billboard.ChartData('hot-100')
print(chart)
```

it throws the following error:

```
chart = billboard.ChartData('hot-100')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ChartData'
```

given the fact that I've already managed to make it work, what is the problem here?

**EDIT**

if I print `(billboard.__file__)` in one directory, I get the location:

`/Users/me/Documents/billboard.pyc`.

at a different location, I get:

`/Users/me/Documents/Code/billboard.py`

Comment: What is `import billboard; print(billboard.__file__)`; are you sure you have the right import? You're evidently importing *something*, but that doesn't mean you're importing the *right* thing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe no I'm not. It prints: `python: can't open file 'billboard.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: I would expect it either to give an `ImportError` or to print out the module location. Please give a [mcve] that recreates *"can't open file"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've edited the question for you

Comment: So is either of those the `billboard` you were expecting to import? Have you named your own file `billboard.py`?

Comment: yeah, that was the mistake. fixed. thanks.